# MVC 4.x Validate dropdown and redirect to next page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Beginner question:

I have an MVC app where there are three dropdowns on a page. Currently I'm using AJAX to evaluate a drop down on form submission and modify a CSS class to display feedback if the answer to the question is wrong.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="formQuestion">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>This is a question:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select id="Question1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 answerResult1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit Answer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#formQuestion").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log($('#Question1').val())
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/DSQ1",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { "selectedAnswer1": $('#Question1').val() },
                    success: function (data) { $(".answerResult1").html(data); }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
        public string DSQ1(string selectedAnswer1)
        {
            var message = (selectedAnswer1 == "3") ? "Correct" : "Feed back";
            return message;
        }
```

I have three of these drop downs, that all get evaluated by AJAX in the same way. My question is, how would I go about evaluating all three and then returning a particular View if all three are correct.

I would like to avoid using hard-typed http:// addresses.

Comment: You want to return a view for a popup? Or you want to redirect to a different page?

Comment: @JerdineSabio I would like to redirect to a different page.

Comment: Can you prevent the event handler to submit the answers from posting back and instead call a custrom OnSubmit() function that evaluates the answers and only if all are correct will call the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a global script variable prior to your document ready function, this will determine if the fields are valid. See `var dropdown1Valid = false, ...`.

Then on your ajax success function, you could modify the values there. Say in the ajax below, your answering with first dropdown, if your controller returned Correct, set `dropdown1Valid` to `true`.

Lastly, at the end of your submit function, you could redirect check if all the variables are true, then redirect using `window.location.href="URL HERE` or use html helper url.action `window.location.href="@Url.Action("actionName");`

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        var dropdown1Valid = false;
        var dropdown2Valid = false;
        var dropdown3Valid = false;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#formQuestion").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log($('#Question1').val())
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/DSQ1",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { "selectedAnswer1": $('#Question1').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                       $(".answerResult1").html(data);

                       if(data == "Correct"){
                          // if correct, set dropdown1 valid to true
                          dropdown1Valid = true;
                       }

                       // option 1, put redirect validation here
                       if(dropdown1Valid && dropdown2Valid && dropdown3Valid){
                          // if all three are valid, redirect
                 window.location.href="@Url.Action("actionName","controllerName", new { })";
                       } 
                    }
                });

                // option 2, put redirect validation here
                if(dropdown1Valid && dropdown2Valid && dropdown3Valid){
                   // if all three are valid, redirect
                   window.location.href="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { })";
                } 
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: It may be better to put the redirect logic in the success() callback of that asynchronous ajax call.

Comment: This seems to clear everything out from the selected answer to the variable updated by the controller.

Comment: @Cloz what do you mean by clear everything out from the selected answer? I didn't add any modifications on input field value attribute. I just added the validation logic.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Honestly I'm not sure... When I initially used it it cleared all the data from the ViewBag but for some reason this time everything is staying. Not sure what happened there but it was probably my mistake. Since it's working now I'll mark you answer as the one that works!